# Как перевести все элементы массива в нижний регистр?

Tags: javascript

пробовал с добавлением этого но не помогло-> str.toLowerCase()

```js
let str = ["Abba", "asd"]
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  let s = str[i].toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join("")
  if (str[i] == s) {
    console.log("true")
    console.log(s)
  }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос про изменение элементов массива, в коде - поиск анаграммы = Error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const str = ["Abba", "asd"];
console.log(str.map(e => e.toLowerCase()));
```

```js
const str = ["Abba", "asd"];

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  let s = str[i].toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join("")
  if (str[i].toLowerCase() === s) {
    console.log("true");
    console.log(s);
  }
}
```